# "You are not in the sudoers file" error after running sudo command

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

I tried using a `sudo` command on my iMac to create a bootable version of Ubuntu, but when I run the command by pressing enter, I got the warning that the command might screw up my system, which I ignored.

I then received a message:

> you are not in the sudoers file, the incident will be reported

and my Terminal window was then rendered useless, with the usual `$` not appearing so that I could type my commands.

What in the world is "sudoers", why is this happening and how can I put a stop to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudoers` is the file that specifies which users are allowed to `sudo`.

You need to run `sudo` from an account that is *Administrator* of your Mac, not a regular user account. Change the association in *System Preferences*.